# Crash on glBufferData

Tags: c++, opengl

I have random crashes at glBufferData, and it only happens on Windows. Mac OS and Linux have no problems. That is my upload function which uploads everything I kept in memory to GPU. `vertex` is a float vector array which is:

```
std::vector<float> vertex[MAX_VBO];
```

and the code randomly crashes at the first glBufferData function, I am calling that random because it can work sometimes, but when my vertex data is huge it is almost guaranteed to crash.

```
void VertexBuffer::upload() {
    glGenBuffers(5, vbo);

    printf("VBO %d - %d - %d\n", vertex[vboPosition].size(), vertex[vboNormal].size(), indices.size());
    if (vertex[vboPosition].size() > 0) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[vboPosition]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex[vboPosition].size() * sizeof(float)*4, &vertex[vboPosition][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }


    if (vertex[vboNormal].size() > 0) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[vboNormal]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex[vboNormal].size() * sizeof(float)*3, &vertex[vboNormal][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }


    if (vertex[vboColor].size() > 0) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[vboColor]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex[vboColor].size() * sizeof(float)*4, &vertex[vboColor][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }


    if (vertex[vboUV].size() > 0) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[vboUV]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex[vboUV].size() * sizeof(float)*2, &vertex[vboUV][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }


    if (vertex[vboTangent].size() > 0) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[vboTangent]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex[vboTangent].size() * sizeof(float)*3, &vertex[vboTangent][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboind);
    if (indices.size() > 0) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboind);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    }
    printf("Success \n");
}
```

More info: I have tried both release and debug mode in case microsoft compiler puts weird stuff between vectors (not continuous etc.) but it is the same. Also I am using OpenGL 3.3 core profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the size you're passing to `glBufferData()` is much bigger than the actual size of the data. For example in this one:

```
std::vector<float> vertex[MAX_VBO];
    ...
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex[vboPosition].size() * sizeof(float)*4,
            &vertex[vboPosition][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Since `vertex[vboPosition]` is an vector of floats, calling `.size()` on it returns the number of floats in the vector. You then multiply that value by `sizeof(float)` **and** by 4, which ends up multiplying it by 16. But one `float` is only 4 bytes, so this is 4 times too much.

The 2nd argument is the amount of data to load in bytes. So the correct calculation is:

```
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex[vboPosition].size() * sizeof(float),
            &vertex[vboPosition][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The same thing applies to all the other `glBufferData()` calls.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I put *4 because each position has 4 floats (x,y,z,w). I was actually going to use glm::vec4 but since the vertex attributes don't have the same sizes, I simply decided to use float.

Comment: I am sorry you are correct, I just forgot to fix it for the UVs. Thank you.